# Wordpress meta query not working

Tags: wordpress

I have an ajax function to load more journey. I want to get the journeys with start date from today.
This is my query:

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$not__in = $_POST['not__in'];
$post__not_in = explode(',', $not__in);
$lang =  $_POST['lang'];
$ship_id =  $_POST['ship_id'];
$today_date = date("Y-m-d");
$args = array (
            'showposts' => 20,
            'post_type' => 'journeys',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $page,
            'post__not_in' => $post__not_in,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'journey_start_date',
                    'value' => $today_date,
                    'type' => 'date',
                    'compare' => '>'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'journey_on_board_of',
                    'value' => $ship_id,                        
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )                   
            )   
        );      
$the_journeys = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Query result when i var_dump $the_journeys:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = 'post_journeys' JOIN wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code=l.code AND l.active=1 
WHERE 1=1  
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (7876,7878,7880,7884) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'journeys' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND t.language_code='en'  
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Why my query not have condition about date?

Comment: `Why my query not have condition about date? ` didn't get you.

Comment: Can you try with Numeric instead of date type? Please refer the note "The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format." over here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query